# Objective-c UITapGestureRecognizer unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a UITableView with cells that contain a UILabel. When I tap the UILabel, I'd want to execute an action, therefore I added a UITapGestureRecognizer.

```
UILabel *telephone = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:420];
telephone.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapToCall = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:telephone action:@selector(tapToCall:)];
[telephone addGestureRecognizer:tapToCall];
```

Then I defined the selector method:

```
-(void)tapToCall: (UITapGestureRecognizer*) sender {
    UILabel *telephone = (UILabel *) sender.view;
    NSLog(@"%@", telephone.text);
}
```

But now I receive an error when I touch the UILabel:

`2017-03-07 13:17:49.220 [37354:2794848] -[UILabel tapToCall:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc39f459250`

`2017-03-07 13:17:49.253 [37354:2794848] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel tapToCall:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc39f459250'`

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

change the target from `initWithTarget:telephone` (not for the particular Control)

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapToCall = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:telephone
```

to `initWithTarget:self` (need to invoke in current class)

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapToCall = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
```

**full answer**

```
UILabel *telephone = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:420];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapToCall = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapToCall:)];
telephone.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[telephone addGestureRecognizer:tapToCall];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change like this

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapToCall = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapToCall:)];
[telephone addGestureRecognizer:tapToCall];
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
UILabel *telephone = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:420];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer   alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

[telephone addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

 - (void)handleTap: (UITapGestureRecognizer*) sender {

    UILabel *telephone = (UILabel *) sender.view;

    NSLog(@"%@", telephone.text);
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)telephone.tag);

     switch(telephone.tag) {
        case 0: { }
            break;
        case 1: { }
            break;
    }
}
```